# Use PuTTY to upload files inside a batch file

Tags: batch-file, putty, psftp

In my batch file I have the following code:

```
cd /D "C:\Putty.0.63"
psftp -b D:\batch\psftp.txt user@ftp.server.com -pw myPassword

pause
```

`psftp.exe` is in the `C:\Putty.0.63` location.

In `psftp.txt` I have `open ftp.server.com`

I can log in to the `ftp` server but I don't know how to `put` a file. I tried to `put` cmd in the batch file or the textfile, but nothing works. Looks like  I can't do `put` inside a batch file.

Any ideas?

---

Solved:

In `psftp.txt` I had  :
`open ftp.server.com
 put myFile.sql`

to make it work I removed the first line and just left the `put myFile.sql` in the file. I didn't need the  `open ftp.server.com` because i was already opening the connection in the batch file with `user@ftp.server.com -pw myPassword`

Comment: The `put` goes to the `psftp.txt`. If it does not work for you, we need to know way more details.

Comment: You also definitely need to upgrade your copy of PuTTY/psftp. Version 0.63 is over 5 years old.

Comment: Thank you. I add to remove the line `open ftp.server.com` in my psftp.txt file and just do the put right there.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I add to remove the line"*? Show us! Edit your question to show [mcve].

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: So does this mean that you have resolved your problem?

Comment: Yes. I added +1 to your first answer, but can't mark it as "solution" because it's a comment

Comment: Because it's not an answer. Your question already says that you have tried it before. So I'm not sure what was it that helped you to resolve the problem.

Comment: In the first place I did the  `put` into the `.txt` file, WITH the line `open ftp.server.com`. To resolve the problem i had to remove the `open ftp.server.com` from the text file :)

Comment: OK, so the problem was really that you already opened a connection using `user@ftp.server.com` on command-line and then you tried to open it again using `open ftp.server.com`, what is not only redundant, but likely also failed, as you have omitted the `user@` part.

Comment: that's perfectly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening a connection twice:

1. On psftp command-line using `user@ftp.server.com -pw myPassword`
2. In script file using `open ftp.server.com`.

The `open` command fails, as you are already connected. So the `put` command never executes.